# Manage DNS from IIS 7 Manager

Tags: iis, dns

Hi I'm using IIS 7 Manager to work on my remote web server. I don't have a hosting control panel (Plesk,...), it is better to manage the server with native tools. However IIS 7 manager is only for IIS, obviously. I want to manage DNS from IIS 7 Manager too, is it posibble, is there an add-on kind of thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer entirely depends on what DNS server you are using.

You can write your own IIS 7 UI extensions very easily with .NET. You would access **Microsoft.Web.Management** and **Microsoft.Web.Administration** assemblies found in *%windows%\system32\inetsvr*. You can find articles about how to do this on [IIS.NET](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/172/extending-the-management-ui/). Create your interface and add it to IIS. All of the icons that you see in the IIS manager are the same kind of .NET UI modules that you would write.

That said, you simply need to find a way to modify your DNS settings programmatically to plug into your IIS 7 UI. There is a nice sample for accessing **Microsoft DNS** in the ASP.NET forums [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/589684.aspx).

It shouldn't be hard to code up a quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the windows 2k8 DNS manager (it can be used remotely as well...
(via MMC or administrative tools)

Comment: I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate on my personal machine. DNS manager is not available in MMC or administrative tools.

Comment: oh...  Haven't installed 7 yet. So I guess I would rdp the dns server and manage it from there... at least until a solution comes up...

Comment: this site http://www.win7dll.info/d.html claims there is a dns client mmc dll on 7. can't see what it is good for , but you might check it up.